# how to create Property classes so that i can convert dataset to that to these

Tags: c#

I want to create classes containing properties like:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
```

so that i will be able to convert `dataset` to these property classes.

If some one has idea then please reply to me.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to convert the "dataset" to those property classes ??

Comment: You want to create a `class` representing a *model(database table)* and fill it with data from a `dataset`?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Your question is vague please ellaborate.

Comment: Abdul,  I have many tables in database and i want to handle these through property classes. So it will be a generalized process to handle the processes

Answer (score 1):

You're describing the subset of [Object-Relational Mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) (ORM). Of course there are numerous solutions to your problem.

The standard C#.NET ORM solutions are [Linq to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx) and [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Both have benefits and drawbacks, but Linq to SQL seems a little easier to get the grips of (at least to me).